# How to Redirect from m.hostname to hostname (desktop site)

Tags: javascript, php

By entering the site using mobile device, i made a script to redirect it to mobile version in host

**what i need ::**  i need redirect from mobile view to actual desktop view when the user click a button.

and it should not go to the mobile version when user click any other page or other link..

guess the code will be like this, but when redirects to an anouther link may it open a mobile site ?

```
 <a href="www.domainname.com">click here to view desktop site</a>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You (probably) placed the mobile redirect script in desktop version which *always* kicks in. You need to set a cookie on mobile page (e.g. `no_further_redirect`) and check its presence on desktop.

Comment: You could add a parameter to your link, which if found would prevent the redirect to the mobile, ie. `<a href="www.domainname.com?ref=mobile">`.

Comment: handling cookies with various mobile browser is efficient .. or any better way

Comment: You can check for screen size and redirect to desktop size when screen size is larger than a specific size (e.g. 991px width). You could do the same for the desktop version of your website.

Comment: was made a cofig in host to detect the OS and redirect according to it, now need to view a desktop view in mobile

Comment: @Sarath you can use the config file to set the cookie, too.

Comment: Set a GET param in the link(?view=desktop), then save in cookie, when navigating check for the value (to redirect or not redirect)

Comment: @KA_lin is there any better way to set it in host.. the recommended solution is to check in each page.. but am searching for a solution to set a config once and not in the all pages.. thanks

Comment: Or use responsive design, if you encounter a weird tablet (for example) ...so get_browser might be tricky (http://php.net/manual/ro/function.get-browser.php), even with a library that detects the device ( ex: http://detector.dmolsen.com/)